# iOS : Access top microphone for video recording

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I believe that AVFoundation defaults the microphone input to the bottom microphone. I want to be able to record my video with audio being picked up by the top microphone. I know this is achievable with simple audio recording(AVAuioSession), but can it be done with video recording?